# How do you use JSHint and Browserify together?

Tags: javascript, jshint, browserify

I'm attempting to build a project using Angular and Browserify. My `controllers.js` file looks like this...

```
'use strict';

module.exports.testController = function($scope){
    $scope.message = 'Controller 1';
    console.log( 'hello' );
};
```

As you may expect, that generates three linting errors.

- Use the function form of Strict
- 'module' is not defined
- 'console' is not defined

I did find a bit of a solution [here](https://coderwall.com/p/-h1h1w) that enables JSHint to process Node.js files by putting `jslint node: true` at the top of the file like this

```
   /*jslint node: true */
   'use strict';

    module.exports.testController = function($scope){
        $scope.message = 'Controller 1';
        console.log( 'hello' );
    };
```

However, that obviously fixes too much; 'console.log(...)' should still be undefined.

Does anyone know how to use JSHint with Browserify?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As of version [2.5.3](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/releases/tag/2.5.3) JSHint supports the `browserify` flag.

Like all flags you can use it directly in a source file:

```
/*jshint browserify: true */
// browserify code here
```

Or add it to a `.jshintrc` file:

```
{
   "browserify": true
}
```

Comment: No matter what I do, I simply cannot get the `.jshintrc` solution working with JSHint v2.9.2.

Answer (score 3):

I hate answering my own questions, it feels like theft, but nevertheless, here's the answer. There's a couple of ways to skin this particular cat, but this solution is probably the most *"correct"*...

---

### Modify .jshintrc

The first thing you should do is modify your .jshintrc so

```
"globals": {
    "define": false
}
```

becomes

```
"globals": {
    "define": false,
    "module": false
}
```

---

### Modify the code

Now you need to modify the code like this

```
module.exports = (function(){

    'use strict';

    var myComponent = {};

    myComponent.testController = function($scope){

        $scope.message = 'hello';
        console.log( 'Hello' );

    };

    myComponent.testDirective= function($scope){

        $scope.message = 'hello';
        console.log( 'Hello' );

    };

    return myComponent;

}());
```

Now JSHint will show linting errors for `console.log` but not for `modules`. This is courtesy of the `.jshintrc` ammend.

The `use strict` linting error is fixed my wrapping all the code in a function.

---

### require()

Taking this a step further, since we're using browserify, we'll also need `require()`. So I need to modify `.jshintrc` one more time.

```
"globals": {
    "module": false,
    "require": false
}
```

**Note:** I've removed `define` from globals because I'm not using it.

Comment: why `false` for those globals? why not true?

Comment: "If value is false (default), JSHint will consider that variable as read-only. Use it together with the undef option...." So basically, if I accidentally try to overwrite any of those globals JSHint will tell me.

Comment: oh ok, I had assumed false was for explicitly disabling those globals. thanks