# Are browserified files expected not to pass jshint validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, jshint

Consider the following:

```
$ cat example.js 
function f () { return 1; }
exports.F = f;
$ browserify example.js > exampleBundle.js 
$ jshint --verbose example.js
$ jshint --verbose exampleBundle.js 
exampleBundle.js: line 1, col 187, Missing semicolon. (W033)
exampleBundle.js: line 1, col 279, Missing semicolon. (W033)
exampleBundle.js: line 1, col 301, Missing semicolon. (W033)
exampleBundle.js: line 1, col 321, Missing semicolon. (W033)
exampleBundle.js: line 1, col 407, Missing semicolon. (W033)
exampleBundle.js: line 5, col 15, Missing semicolon. (W033)

6 errors
$
```

Also, for what it's worth, [jquery-1.11.1.min.js](http://jquery.com/download/) does not pass jshint validation.

Moreover, I am using version 4.2.1 of browserify and 2.5.6 of jshint:

```
$ browserify --v
4.2.1
$ jshint --v
jshint v2.5.6
$
```

Finally, if I modify the `.jshintrc` file to include a statement of the form (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105555/1355058)):

```
$ cat .jshintrc 
{
    "browserify": true
}
$
```

the errors still remain.

**First version of the post (BEGIN)**

In the first version of the post I was getting an error that the option was not supported:

```
example.js: line 0, col 0, Bad option: 'browserify'. (E001)
```

However, as it was pointed out I was running a version of jshint before 2.5.3 (in particular 2.5.2).

**First version of the post (END)**

Regardless though, the question still remains: Is this expected? It looks like browserify is generating code that can not be validated by jshint.

Comment: It's pretty obvious, but still I would ask. Do you have correct version of jshint? The link mentions the version 2.5.3...

Comment: Thank you. I was indeed running 2.5.2 and I now installed 2.5.6. However, the errors remain (apart from the `bad option` message that I had in my first version of the post).

Comment: From [substack](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/157): _Running jshint against generated source does indeed seem pretty silly. If you want to jshint, why not run it against the original source files?_

Comment: I do and you are right. In fact I have a script written in javascript (so, it works on any platform) that I call using node so that I can automate the process of generating the bundles. A similar script is used so that I can validate the original code. So, in that respect I have no issues. On the other hand, the question is if this is expected behaviour. Inspecting the bundle, jshint is absolutely right on the "errors" that it throws.

Answer (score 2):

Of course generated JS files would not pass jshint.

Remember that the purpose of tools like jshint is to point out mistakes you may have made in your code.  In theory, enforcing the use of a strict subset of JavaScript syntax helps prevent you from making errors and makes your code easier for you and other humans to understand in the future.

The output of tools like browserify and minification is not meant for human consumption.  Minifiers intentionally take advantage of syntax that is technically-legal but human-unfriendly in order to achieve maximum byte savings.

Consider:

```
if (iAmThirsty == true) {
    drinkBeer();
}
```

Through a combination of renaming and syntax transforms, a minifier might turn this into something like:

```
t&&d()
```

Because `&&` short-circuits, these do the same thing.  The latter would certainly not pass jshint (or code review), but that doesn't matter.  You *wrote* something that is easy for humans to digest, and that is what will be modified in the future.

You will never work with processed output; you will always modify the original source and compile again.  Jshint exists to make sure your *source* is high-quality.  Running it on processed output doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you try the example that I gave?

Comment: I don't see what you're getting at -- your example just runs jshint against the processed output of browserify, which doesn't make sense for the reasons I've outlined above.

Comment: No, because browserify is not a minimizer and jshint validates code; code that our browsers run. In particular, the very first statement where jshint complains is this: `throw new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'")` where a semicolon is missing. Moreover, browserify was also using semicolons to indicate end of statements. In other words, jshint throws a perfectly valid error.

Comment: It doesn't matter that browserify doesn't minify your code (though it [can](https://www.npmjs.org/package/minifyify)), the point is that browserify's output **is not meant for humans** and therefore it does not make sense to run jshint on that output.  Browserify's wrapper code comes pre-minified.  If you want to run jshint on the browserify wrapper, run it on the [**original**, pre-compiled source](https://github.com/substack/browser-pack/blob/master/prelude.js).  **jshint does not validate the code that browsers run, it validates the code that humans write**.