# gulp-jshint utters errors when using browserify

Tags: gulp, browserify, jshint

I am using gulp-jshint with browserify. browserify will generate a lot of code that fails jshint. I have read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25105555/1183252) that there is an option to set `"browserify": true` since JSHint 2.5.3. However, this option will be ignored by gulp-jshint.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Can I use jshint and not gulp-jshint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I screwed up. Of course I should lint my source files, not the file that browserify generated.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but I think I am calling JSHint on the source files: gulp.task('default',  ['lint', 'browserify', 'connect'] ); Where lint is the JSHint component - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @mcneela86 The tasks you define in the array will run in parallel: *"Note: The tasks will run in parallel (all at once), so don't assume that the tasks will start/finish in order."* from https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#gulptaskname-deps-fn but this might help you: http://davidwalsh.name/gulp-run-sequence